# Go to the end of the list as soon as you create it, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I read many great answers about a ScrollController in the ListView. Then when a button is clicked we do `scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);`

My question is, can we go to the **bottom of a List**, but at the **creation** of it ?

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        // CAN WE DO SOMETHING HERE FOR EXAMPLE ?
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index)
        {
          return Item(data[index]);
        }
    );
```

(For me, it's a chat so the `reverse` option doesn't look good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you said, you are using this list for a chat log, then the `reverse` options does work for you. You just have to also invert your chat log data:

```
data.reversed.toList()
```

There is not direct option on a ListView to go to the end of the list.

---

For a more complete example from one of my applications:

```
class MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageList(this.displayMessages);

  final List<Map> displayMessages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: displayMessages.map((message) {
            return ChatMessage(message);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
displayMessages = List<Map>.from(clientMessages.data).reversed.toList();
```

Comment: The reverse function puts the latest messages on top. I would like the last messages to be at the bottom (if you want to see the old ones you have to scroll up). That's why going directly to the bottom was interesting in my case

Comment: Hence the double reverse. You reverse the `ListView` `reverse: true` and you reverse the data you are putting into that `ListView`: `data.reversed.toList()`. I've been using this for years, it's the simplest solution.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad it worked very well. Thanks a lot !